# Image disappears after moving it with CSS command "object-position: 30px"

Tags: html, css

I want my img to be at the right side of my website. But instead this happens.
[This is after I add `object-position: 30px;`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Vf4a.jpg)[And this is before I add the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8Xsb.jpg)
in my CSS code for that image.

My html:

```
<img class="searchloop" src="images/searchloop.png" alt="Search..." width="35" height="35">
```

My CSS:

```
img.searchloop {
    object-position: 30px;
}
```

I already tried `object-position: top right` but nothing happened. I want the image to be at the right side of my Website. But when I move it with `object-position:`  it gets covered by something and I dont understand why. Does someone know why that happens?

Comment: hard to tell without the rest of the code, but it looks like the element's box is not wide enough to move it all the way to the right side.

Comment: As @Stephan mentioned. It looks like the img has a width of 35px and you have moved the image 30px within this, leaving just a little bit of your image displayed. 

From MDN: The object-position CSS property specifies the alignment of the selected replaced element's contents within the element's box. See some examples here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position